# How to add an incrementing number to lines matching a pattern w/ Bash (awk)

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file with numerous comment lines randomly thrown in formatted as such

```
Comment,blahblahblah
Comment,blahblahblah
Comment,blahblahblah
```

I want to add an incrementing number to comment lines such as

```
Comment,1 blahblahblah
Comment,2 blahblahblah
Comment,3 blahblahblah
```

I tried this with no luck

```
awk '{for(x=1;x<=NF;x++)if($x~/Comment,/){sub(/Comment,/Comment, ++i)}}1' filename
```

Comment: if your input file can contain lines that do not contain "Comment" then include those in your sample input/output as it makes a significant difference to which solution is best.

Answer (score 1):

The second argument to `sub()` should be a string, which requires quotes around `Comment,`.

There's also no need to loop through the columns, you can simply match the whole line.

```
awk '/Comment,/ { sub(/Comment,/, "Comment, " ++i) }1' filename
```

Answer (score 1):

another `awk`

```
$ awk '{i+=sub(/^Comment,/,"&" i+1 " ")}1' file

Comment,1 blahblahblah
Comment,2 blahblahblah
Comment,3 blahblahblah
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need `awk` for this (unless you need it to be fast).

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
counter=0
while IFS= read -r line; do
  [[ $line = *Comment,* ]] && line=${line//Comment,/Comment,$((++i)) }
  printf '%s\n' "$line"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{gsub("Comment,","Comment,"NR,$0);print;}' filename
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer, it would be helpful to comment what the person was missing instead of just providing one line of code. Good luck on StackOverflow!